# How to speed up shutil.copy()?

Tags: python, shutil

Here I'm using the code in python like:

```
if option2 == 1:
    try:
        global option2, Nimages

        for sur in fm_path:
            shutil.copy(sur,file1) # here how to speed up the copy function

        option2 = 0
    except shutil.Error as e:
        print('Error: %s' % e)
```

While executing this, if I copy a lengthy file it took too much time to copy. Any suggestion to reduce the time?

Comment: Is it slower than copying the same file from command line? How much?

Comment: if i use ctr + c and v its little bit fast when compare to this...! I'm using linux mint

Comment: I propose to do some more thorough tests on the speed before assuming results.  Often copying is greatly influenced by caching sources or even delaying writing of the copies, so to get solid results you should copy much more than should fit in the caches (i. e. it would be best to compare this with gigabytes of data).

Answer (score 15):

If you are dealing with files with big size, you could try to do file open/write as a copy. As mentioned in [Faster Python File Copy](http://blogs.blumetech.com/blumetechs-tech-blog/2011/05/faster-python-file-copy.html), the default buffer size in `shutil.copyfileobj` (which is the real function doing file-copy in `shutil`) is 16*1024, 16384. You can use bigger buffer size then.

ex,

```
with open(src, 'rb') as fin:
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fout:
        shutil.copyfileobj(fin, fout, 128*1024)
```

Comment: here what is 'rb' and 'wb. bcz I have assigned only source and destination. Else I have to define that rb and wb? is it in built?

Comment: 'rb' stands for `read binary`; 'wb' stands for `write binary`. Both are just strings. You should check the help of `open`.

Comment: See my code above, after for loop I had paste yours, but not works. It shows Directory error in fout. I'm copying the image file to one directory[Folder]. I think ur code is for file to file operation. . .Kindly check and clarify...

Comment: Yes, it is just for file-wise copying. You need to do folder-wise by yourself. Or you can pursue to `shutil.copytree`. But for your goal, *speed up*, you need to adjust buffer size for file copying.

Comment: That's amazing--this sped up my file copying by almost 10x

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Python 3.8, `shutils` offers platform-specific faster alternatives to copy files. Read more about it here:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil-platform-dependent-efficient-copy-operations